# What is Behind the Scene in JVM for Overriding(data members and methods)?

Tags: java, oop, jvm, overriding

i have these class after determining the output i couldn't understand what the behind the scene that why data members and method, even a class load in method area.thanks in advance

```
class Base {
    public int a = 32;

    public void signature() {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }

}

class Child extends Base {
    public int a = 25;

    public void signature() {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base = new Child();
        System.out.println(base.a);
        base.signature();
    }
}
```

OutPut:

```
32
Child
```

I understand child method called on base class because method calling depend on run time object binding but why it print 32 even base variable has Child object reference.?

Comment: Soltirios i understand but i need to know why we cannot override the data members? how JVM treat data members and method?